# SSIS data conversion issue of decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a dtsx package running in SSIS on our SQL server (2016 SP2 CU6), its a lightweight task of importing an Excel (xlsx) worksheet into a table in SQL as-is, no transformations needed at this stage, there is an agent job that does a lot more around it but I can see the fault is occurring in just this section.

The issue I am seeing is that a number in Excel (`0.0153`) comes out in SQL as if converted badly (`1.5299999999999999E-2`).

To confirm the number in Excel is `0.0153` and not something longer or formatted to look like this.

[image: Both values are just 6 characters in length, formula bar shows actual value]

After the import this is what I have: -

[image: Both values show in SQL]

I find this odd as: -

- They are both in a very similar situation but with different outcomes
- They are one after the other in the Excel worksheet
- They are near the top of the worksheet (rows 10 and 11) so sampling should be using them to understand the data type if there is anything like that happening (row 1 is `0.193841` which is also similar, overall range is -29 to 200 with up to 7 decimal places)
- There is only 0.0021 difference between them

The number format in Excel is `General` and the column in SQL is `NVARCHAR(255)`

In the SSIS package the Excel source DataType for the *External Column* is being classed as `double-precision float [DT-R8]` (not sure where that comes from but I have no ability to change it) and the *Output Column* is `Unicode string [DT-WSTR]`

I am then using `Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0` OLD DB Connection to get to the table.

Its a simple package but why is this value jumping so wildly. Its not a one off, the input has around 1700 rows and we see this on a number of rows.

[image: Package layout]

Comment: What is the datatype of your column `SBU_ANAL_FIELD_5` in your database? Why are you changing the datatype to a `DT_WSTR` when it's a numerical value?

Comment: On your comment *"not sure where that comes from but I have no ability to change it"* about the `double-precision float [DT-R8]` data type, that's a "feature" of the ACE drivers. They are "kind" (foolish) enough to choose and enforce the datatype choice for you when reading data, which is based on the top *x* number of rows (can't recall the default value for *x*, I feel like it might be 9 (the top 10 rows including the header)).

Comment: Scientific notation does not mean it is converted "badly". Anyway why are you storing numbers as strings?

Comment: Excel uses floating-point to store numbers, and `0.0153` cannot be represented exactly. Excel will certainly *pretend* that's an exact value to the best of its ability, but it's not. Unless your column is actually text (i.e. the expression that generates the value is `"0.0153"`) you'll get a floating-point, and it's up to you to either round it to the desired precision, or use a `FLOAT` type for the destination column so this rounding can be further postponed to when clients process it.

Comment: In truth, I'm not surprised that a value previously defined as a float is using scientific notation when converted to a string.

Comment: Note that `0.0132` won't have an exact representation either, but you happen to "luck out" when it's converted to a string, in that the representation happens to match what you want: compare `SELECT FORMAT(0.0132e, 'G17'), FORMAT(0.0153e, 'G17')`. (The text you have is not the result of T-SQL's `FORMAT` but the internal conversion routines of SSIS, but the same idea applies.)

Comment: I laughed out loud when I read "Lightweight task of importing Excel spreadsheet". If you can, save it as a pipe or tab delim file first and you'll have 100% less headaches. That's the best advice I can offer here. There are a thousand "gotchas" when trying to extract data from Excel. Excel is not a viable data source.

Comment: @Larnu SBU_ANAL_FIELD_5 is NVARCHAR(255)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda 'badly' may be bad choice of word, 'unexpectedly'. Because it is coming from a user and they can do all sorts of interesting things, I import it all as text into a staging folder, I then parse that and 'clean' and import it from there.

Comment: Why are you importing a value that is clearly a numerical value as an `nvarchar`? A Numerical value won't have any unicode characters (so using 2 bytes per character is a waste of space), and strings don't act the same way as numbers; Unless you want the behaviour  lke `'251.903134' < '3.9557' = TRUE`

Comment: @JacobH I need the user to have as few steps as possible unfortunately I can't flex and change this. You are right, out of Excel and *a lot* of headaches would go.

Comment: I've had all kinds of issues importing Excel because of data types. I ended up using an external tool downloaded from ZappySys https://zappysys.com and charged the client.

Comment: You cannot "import it all as text" cleanly because, despite appearances, Excel does not store the values in question as text. In other words, when you get `0.0153`, it is already stored and returned as a floating-point value, and storing it as text then *already* involves a conversion. If you're OK with round-tripping floating point to text and back, see if [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/) helps. I'm not sure if this can be embedded in the SSIS connection string.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yes, `IMEX=1` can help here, although it pays to keep in mind that utilising it essentially trades a pit of snakes for another, different but not more pleasant one. In particular, any kind of cell formatting will make its way into the staging table - think national-specific currency symbols, thousand separators, accounting formats, you name it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a corporate environment we can't always choose the source and destination data, and sometimes we just have to "make it work".  Excel is a nightmare in SSIS especially, all it takes is one wrong change to the input file and your job fails because metadata doesn't match anymore.

Yes, ideally this is numeric data and should be stored in a numeric data field (not a string/character field).

This is how I've accomplished this scenario in the past, hopefully it will work for your situation, but really depends on what the resulting data will be used for.

1. Add a Data Conversion step in your data flow task to convert the double-precision float value to a decimal (I used scale=10)

[image: Data Flow Task]
[image: Data Conversion - to Decimal]
 2. Add a second Data Conversion step to convert the decimal value back to a Unicode string

[image: Data Conversion - to String]
 3. Change your OLE DB destination mapping to use the new output column from the second Data Conversion task.

[image: Column mapping]

Result:

[image: Database result]

Comment: I could write up a document on my final resolution, but answer along with the floating point comments (although some were a bit short tempered I felt) got me there (and educated me!).

Answer (score 0):

To me it works as well to set from Excel source output as dt decimal then can have only one conversion - to string.